# How to install Flash Player debugger on Windows 8.1 in IE

Tags: flash, debugging

The goal is to install FLash Player debugger on IE 10 and Windows 8.1. I just finished installing 8.1 and now the "normal" player is installed.

I downloaded the latest version with debugging. 
http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html#fp11

When I start the Flash Player debugger installer (as administrator), it stops and display a "nice" message informing me that Flash is now integrated into IE and it will update itself with the latest version on it own and cancels the install.

Answer (score 1):

I find a way which works for my window8.1 and IE11.
Try by yourself:

(1): Open ie, Check add-on manager, see if shockwave flash plugin is enabled

(2): go to C:\Windows\System32, rename C:\Windows\System32\Macromed to be other name: such as: COPY_Macromed
create a new folder with same name: Macromed, create sub folder: Macromed\Flash
go to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 do same as above, rename and create a new one.

(3): go to : https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html
download : Download the Flash Player for Windows 8 x64 debugger and run it.

(4): restart computer for this windows update.

(5): Open ie: go to : https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html, now if you can see the Flash animation, right click to see if you have : debugger, if yes , then it's installed.

Comment: When I try step 3, it fails for me. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first uninstall the existing Flash Player before installing the debug version.  On the same page where you download the debug player (http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html), there's a link for the uninstaller.

Be forewarned, if you have the player installed for both IE and Firefox/Chrome, the uninstaller will remove both.

Comment: I uninstalled Flash using the uninstaller. Note that the Windows 8 version link does not work. I verified that IE no longer display flash content with Adobe test page. I downloaded Windows Flash Player 11.9 ActiveX control content debugger (for IE) flashplayer_11_ax_debug.exe and started the install. I get the same Adobe message about IE will keep Flash up to date. The only option is Cancel.

Comment: Update: The Flash player was still alive. They have a Shockwave and Flash player test page. Of course I tested with Shockwave <sigh>. 
Following the instructions on 
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html 
I ran into the TrustedInstaller that is preventing me from deleting the files. Tried to take ownership so I can delete the files. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is complete crap.

IE needs to allow you install the debug player!  It's not a plugin if i cant UNPLUG IT.  Arrghhh

If you can, just use chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft embedded their own variation of Flash in Windows 8.  This Microsoft/Adobe Flash Player cannot be uninstalled or updated, but can be disabled, which means that the debugger player cannot be installed.

It is particularly disturbing move by both Adobe and Microsoft.  While developers have flocked away from Flash, there are still many valuable products built on it.  Removing the ability to install the debug player insures that companies will no longer be able to maintain or update those products with confidence and quality.  My opinion is that this hastens the demise of Flash.

On the bright-side, it opens up opportunities for developers because companies will need entirely new versions of their software built on modern browser features, which aren't tied to a proprietary platform.